# Using environment variables in Monodevelop with MonoTouch

Tags: mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, environment-variables, monodevelop

I've been trying to mess around with the SGen garbage collector's configurations and as I've seen [here](http://mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen#Configuring_SGen), [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8#Configuration), and in the mono man page, I've got a few environment variables to work with.

As shown in this image, I added them to my project (checked inside the csproj too), and they only get ignored when i run my app. I got all my environment variables using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` and neither `MONO_GC_PARAMS` or `MONO_GC_DEBUG` were there.

So my question is how do I use environment variables in a MonoTouch project?

[image: Project Options]

**Versions**
Monotouch 5.2.10 (Evaluation)
MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5
Mono 2.10.8
Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Can you run the app, then open a terminal window and execute: "ps auxww | grep debugtrack" and add the line for the app's process? I also assume you're using the latest MonoDevelop?

Comment: here you go http://codepad.org/OQsjIwnZ

Comment: Which version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: here's everything in my version info http://codepad.org/qVljoGqY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonoDevelop 2.8.6 does not include support for setting environment variables when executing MonoTouch projects.

The current MonoDevelop beta version (2.8.8.3) does include support for environment variables, so you can install the beta from [here](http://monodevelop.com/Download) if you want to try it out.

Comment: I just tried env vars with 2.8.8.3, and it worked for me. Can you run "ps auxww | grep debugtrack" again now?

Comment: hmm they do seem to show up with that, as you can see here : http://codepad.org/0xl8kBuL but there are still none of them in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(). I don't know if that really means anything.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it feels like I implemented this such a long time ago, but the required environment variable support isn't in MonoTouch 5.2. You'll need MonoTouch 5.3 too (which is in alpha right now). You might be able to get the alpha by checking for updates in MonoDevelop and switch to the alpha channel.